# Stm32+ USB. Пропускание сообщений

Tags: usb, stm32

Создаю устройство на базе stm32, которое подключалось бы к компьютеру на Windows как HID устройство. Для написания программы на stm32 использую связку cubemx+keil. Необходимо организовать простую передачу пакетов по 11 байт. Дескриптор репортов приведён ниже:

```
__ALIGN_BEGIN static uint8_t CUSTOM_HID_ReportDesc_FS[USBD_CUSTOM_HID_REPORT_DESC_SIZE] __ALIGN_END =
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
   0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              //    USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
    // System Parameters
    0xa1, 0x01,                    //   COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_ID (1)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0xFF,                    //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 11,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 8,                       //   REPORT_COUNT (4)
    0xb1, 0x82,                    //   FEATURE (Data,Var,Abs,Vol)
    0x85, 0x01,                    //   REPORT_ID (1)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 1)
    0x91, 0x82,                    //   OUTPUT (Data,Var,Abs,Vol)

    0x85, 0x02,                    //   REPORT_ID (4)
    0x09, 0x02,                    //   USAGE (Vendor Usage 4)
    0x75, 11,                    //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 8,                       //   REPORT_COUNT (4)
    0x81, 0x82,                    //   INPUT (Data,Var,Abs,Vol)
  /* USER CODE END 0 */ 
  0xC0    /*     END_COLLECTION              */

};
```

Столкнулся с проблемой вот какого плана. При передаче чаще чем один пакет в секунду, есть вероятность, что целый пакет не будет отправлен. К примеру, вот написал тестовую программу.

```
uint8_t dataTest[50][11]; //Объявление переменных, естественно,
uint8_t flag=0;           //сделано в нужном месте
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<50;i++)for(uint8_t j=0;j<11;j++)dataTest[i][j]=i; //Заполнение начальными значениями
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */       
        while(USBD_CUSTOM_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, dataTest[flag++], 11)!=USBD_OK);
        if(flag==50)flag=0;
        HAL_Delay(500); 
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Подцепляюсь анализатором Saleae к шине USB и вижу следующую картину. Передалось одиннадцать байт "семёрок", передалось одиннадцать байт "восьмёрок", затем передалось одиннадцать байт "десяток". В ответной программе на компе то же самое. С чем может быть связан переход stm к следующему элементу массива, не дожидаясь даже начала передачи предыдущего?

Comment: Передалось 7777777777 88888888888 1010101010101010101010 это понятно. А как должно быть?

Comment: "99999999999" пропустилось. Это лишь пример. Бывает что не один пакет не отправляется, а несколько, к примеру: 11111111111 22222222222 55555555555 и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Так и не понял в чём был корень проблемы, но решил её следующим образом. Добавил простую реализацию подтверждения приёма пакета компьютером, после которого МК переходит к отправке следующего сообщения из своего буфера.

Answer (score 0):

В USB нельзя просто так слать пакет в энпоинт. Компьютер должен его запросить. Установите период опроса в дескрипторе почаще.